Angular Admin Lte and other resources loading time on IIS
I have bought a Windows server and some of the bundles were missing (URL rewrite). I don't have much experience regarding the server configuration.
I am hosting my angular website on IIS it takes too much time to load.
I am using a module-based structure and Lazy loading
Here is my Network tab screenshot IIS

I have also hosted the same site on Godaddy Plesk. But load time on Plesk is low as compared to IIS
Here is my Network tab screenshot Plesk Godaddy.

I have noticed that the loading time of resources in the IIS server is more time-consuming as compared to the load time in Godaddy Server.

Use Task Manager or Performance Monitor to check your server resource usage, including CPU, memory, and disk usage.

Setting caching policies can reduce server request time and improve performance.
